# How to find data inserted in meteor collection?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

i have collection in client subscribed. After the fresh insert on the collection just redirecting to view page of that inserted collection.

publishing with 'postDetail' collection on server

```
Meteor.publish('postDetail', (postId: string) => {
    return PostCollection.find({ _id: postId });
});
```

insert page:

```
collection.insert(this.currentPost, (error, postId) => {

            if (postId) {
                this.router.navigate(['detail', { postId: postId }]);
            }
            else {

            }
        });
```

in View page :

```
 this.subscribe('postDetail', this.postId, () => {
    collection.findOne({ _id: this.postId}); 
    **// this is not giving the inserted data at first time**
  });
```

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more clear on what your actual question is. The question in the subject is very broad, and best answered by reading the manual. What is your actual problem?

Comment: redirecting on insert success callback but not getting the data in next page.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your subscription, you are using this.subscribe(), which looks like a template level subscription. This subscription will be removed when the template is destroyed (not rendered anymore).

So if you are rerouting to a different template after insert you need to resubscribe in that template too.

(Meteor is smart enough to keep the cached data between the two subscriptions, so the second subscribe will be very fast. But you still have to do it).